# Jquery Mobile ListView Seleted Item CSS Color

Tags: html, css, jquery-mobile

I am creating a list dynamically. I used the onclick event to call a javascript and this works, what I can not do is get the selected item from the list to have a different color.

This is the code example:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>`enter code here`
    <script src="scripts/jquery.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="stylesheets/jquery.mobile.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="scripts/jquery.mobile.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var $al = $("#mylist");
            $al.append("<li ><a id='a1' href=\"#\" rel=\"external\" onclick=\"test('selected test 1'); return false\">TEST 1</a></li>");
            $al.append("<li ><a id='a2' href=\"#\" rel=\"external\" onclick=\"test('seleced test 2'); return false\">TEST 2</a></li>");
        });

        function test(text) {
            $("#divtest").html(text);
        } 

        $("#myList li a").click(function () {
                $('#myList li > div').each(function (index) {
                    $(this).removeClass("ui-btn-active");
                });
                var p = $(this).parent();
                $(p).addClass('ui-btn-active');
            });

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="profile">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        </div>
        <!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul id="mylist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id='divtest'>

        </div>
        <!--/content-->
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        </div>
        <!--/footer-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for all your help, the issue that i had was the remove css part. i update the example for future references.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To do this you need to call .addClass and .removeClass from your list item. Depending on the color you want you will have to remove/add certain classes. For starters you can add the class ui-btn-active to the items.

Comment: Hi thanks, for your answer do you have a example of how to do this, i try to do something like this:         $("#mylist li a").click(function () {
            alert("here");
            $('#mylist li').each(function (index) {
                $(this).removeClass("ui-btn-active");
            });
            alert("add class");
            var p = $(this).parent();
            $(p).addClass('ui-btn-active');
        });

Answer (score 0):

Only thing you need to do is add **data-theme='a'** attribute to li element and pick needed template.

Something more about this attribute: http://jquerymobile.com/demos/1.2.0/docs/content/content-themes.html

You also need to execute **.listview('refresh');** to restyle a listview.

Here's working example from your code: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/z5Vhm/

And here's your code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>`enter code here`
    <link href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.2.0/jquery.mobile-1.2.0.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script>

        $(document).ready(function () {
            var $al = $("#mylist");
            $al.append("<li data-theme='a'><a id='a1' href=\"#\" rel=\"external\" onclick=\"test('selected test 1'); return false\">TEST 1</a></li>");
            $al.append("<li data-theme='b'><a id='a2' href=\"#\" rel=\"external\" onclick=\"test('seleced test 2'); return false\" >TEST 2</a></li>");
            $al.listview('refresh');
        });

        function test(text) {
            $("#divtest").html(text);
        } 

    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="profile">
        <div data-role="header" data-position="fixed">
        </div>
        <!-- /header -->
        <div data-role="content">
            <ul id="mylist" data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div id='divtest'>

        </div>
        <!--/content-->
        <div data-role="footer" data-position="fixed">
        </div>
        <!--/footer-->
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hi Thanks for your response, with this example that you send the color is fix, i only want the one that i click to get the different color, not always. Can you help me with this?

Comment: Give me a some time to fix your example.

Answer (score 0):

You need to find the parent Li for current hyperlink and apply background color to the parent:

```
$('a').click( function() {
  $(this).parent().css({'background-color' : 'red' });
});
```

Check this jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/p42SX/3/